# Echo cancellation on Twilio platform

Tags: ios, audio, codec, twilio

We're thinking of using the Twilio to place and receive calls with an iOS app. Does the Twilio platform handle echo cancellation, or is this something we need to implement? The documentation does not specify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob from Twilio here.

Stoked that you're looking at building something with Twilio Client on iOS.  Our SDK uses the CoreAudio API so it takes advantage of the hardware echo cancellation available on each device.

You don't need to configure anything to use it.  If you're looking to get started quickly, feel free to check out [our quickstart guide here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) or leverage my colleague Devin's [Twilio Client Cocoapod](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/08/installing-twilio-client-for-ios-using-cocoapods-2.html?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).  Hope that helps!

Comment: Does the Android SDK do the same? Is there anything special that needs setting up?

Comment: Hi @Rob Spectre, I would like to hear if any such solution is available for Android. I am facing similar issue.